# .net mvc equivalent to JSF ui:include

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, include

I am moving from a JSF project to a .net project. One of the great things about facelets is the ability to use `<ui:include>` to modularise your html into small fragments that are easier to manage and reuse.

So far, I have not yet seen anything in .net MVC that can give this same flexibility.

Any advice/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you are using asp.net mvc 3 or 4, you can use in the view @Html.renderpartial, even if you using from controller there is a PartialViewResult